# Linux command line utility for watching log files live?

Tags: linux, logging

What's a good linux command line utility for watching a log file live? It's probably obvious but I totally forgot it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are two things that leap immediately to mind...

tail -f

or

multitail

Comment: thank you sir. I'll give ya the answer since Linker3000 has so many points, but I still appreciate the help!

Comment: also less -F /path to log  (i.e. less -F /var/log/messages)

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are in the same folder as the logfile:

tail -f logfilename

Answer (score 3):

If you want to watch a specific aspect of your file, say just IPs in an access log, you can do :

```
tail -f your_file | cut -d' ' -f1 | logtop
```

assuming that IPs are the first column of your log file.

Answer (score 3):

The `tailf` command is functionally equivalent to `tail -f` but better in terms of performance. From `man tailf`:

> tailf  will  print out the last 10 lines of a file and then wait for the file to grow.
>     It is similar to tail -f but does
>          not access the file when it is not growing.  This has the side effect of not updating the access time for the file, so  a
>          filesystem flush does not occur periodically when no log activity is happening.
>   tailf  is  extremely useful for monitoring log files on a laptop when logging is infrequent and the user desires that the
>          hard disk spin down to conserve battery life.